# (TS) Can not find name 'using'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image]

As soon as I connect JavaScript to the project there are errors

> (TS) Can not find name 'using'.
>
> (TS) Can not find name 'System'.

and so on.
I do not understand what's the matter.
the project is crashed

[image]

Comment: There's some kind of problem with your setup, since it appears as though your BundleConfig.cs file is not getting compiled correctly. Probably an extension. Try restarting in safe mode: [Command line to start visual studio and disable add ins/Extensions for that instance](//stackoverflow.com/q/10655732)

Comment: That BundleConfig.cs file is not saved correctly or there's something wrong with it. VS is not even able to parse it, as you can see by the lack of proper syntax highlighting

Comment: What is "(TS)"?

Comment: @user2864740 `(TS)` is the TypeScript analyzer built into VS, shows syntax and other errors for JavaScript and TypeScript